# DIVI site modifications blocked due to "blank referrer" - any workarounds?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We are using DIVI on a shared hosting site. When using the DIVI Visual Editor, apparently some Ajax calls are being detected by the hoster as an threat, and the IP is then block for 10 minutes or so. The only remedy on the hoster side, they say, is to whitelist the IP; however, none of our WordPress contributors have a static IP, so this will change frequently.

Assuming the analysis of the issue is correct, might there be a mechanism to 'fix' the blank referrer before the request leaves the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding an access control header to htaccess, if you haven't already.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Additionally, you could sign up for a VPN service that has a static IP, and have your contributors log in to the VPN prior to logging in to WP.  From a security standpoint, this might be a better way to go in the long run if you have people accessing your site from many (possibly unsafe) places.

Comment: yeah the VPN option occurred to me, but rather than add another hop in the mix, I'd be inclined to switch hosters to one that can accomodate this better